# How to make openssl_decrypt working in php 5

Tags: php

**`openssl_decrypt`** is not working in **PHP 5**. My server is **PHP 5** and I cannot change its version. It uses many other functions  and if I upgrade that won't work.
My local machine is **PHP 7** and the **`openssl_decrypt`** is working there.

So how can I make working the ***`openssl_decrypt`*** in PHP 5. Or any other alternative ways?

Also a folder say '*newfolder*' in my server is PHP 7. Here **`openssl_decrypt`**  works. But I call the script(which uses **`openssl_decrypt`** function) from any other location from my server it always return false.

**EDIT**

PHP version of server is **5.3.28**

Below is the code

```
$decrypt_text = openssl_decrypt($encryptedtext, "AES-128-CTR", $encrypt_key, 0, '1010101010101010');
```

`$decrypt_text` gives `false` in **php 5.3.28.**

Got warning on error reporting.

**Warning: openssl_decrypt() [function.openssl-decrypt]: Unknown cipher algorithm**

But works in **php 7.**

So issue is something related to php version.

Comment: Uh, you know that PHP5 was introduced in 2004 ... and reached end of life/end of support in 2018: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php.  Nevertheless, openssl_decrypt *should* work with PHP5.3 and higher: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php.  Q: What is your version of PHP5?  Q: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: You dont say what "not working" means so I'll assume it means the method is not defined? Otherwise please provide more details. Also, this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/323005/php-openssl-extension-has-a-package

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php

Comment: PHP 5.3.28 is nearly eight years old and hasn't seen bugfixes since years. I hope you are not doing anything that really needs encryption with that code

Answer (score 0):

The error is explaining that the cipher algorithm used `AES-128-CTR` is unknown. Check which cipher algorithms are available in that version of PHP using `openssl_get_cipher_methods`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php